# Is it possible to have Maxima identifiers constructed as the program executes?

Tags: maxima

Is it possible to have Maxima identifiers constructed as the Maxima program executes? Specifically in functions definitions, if that matters.

So I could, for example, use function calls like
`A(N,T,suffix)`
or
`A(N,T,"suffix")`
(both usage variants suit me) and get **expressions** like
`f_suffix`
with *suffix* in them being the actual symbol (or string) in the 3rd argument of the A call in the example.

Comment: Well, you can create a symbol by concatenating pieces via `concat`. See also `gensym` which generates a new (until now unreferenced) symbol. However, if you write a symbol with a subscript, it is treated, for the most part, as a distinct variable. The subscript can be anything (number, symbol, string, or expression). E.g. instead of `concat('x, '_foo)` to create `x_foo`, try `x[foo]` instead. In general I recommend subscripts instead of `concat`, but maybe the best approach will become clearer if you say more about what you want to accomplish.

Comment: I want to use a function which will look at that argument and based on its value it will construct a function name and several variables names and use those in its calculation. I didn't want any hash arrays or such, to not clutter the expressions.
Your suggestion with [] seems to work and mind you, I'd never find it by myself). Here're the use-case I want:
a_h(N,T,ph,s) :=  C_1[s] * z_[ph](N,T) ;

Comment: Do I understand correctly that `z_` is a function of N and T, and parameterized by ph? If so, that's a good fit for Maxima's so-called array functions, defined as `foo[x](y, z) := ... (expression involving x, y, and z) ...`. Then for each x, `foo[x]` is a lambda expression (unnamed function) which has arguments y and z. By the way if you are writing `z_[ph]`, you might consider omitting the underscore, so just `z[ph]`. You can also omit the function definition, and just leave `z[ph](N, T)` as an unbound term, same as with other expressions involving undefined functions.

Comment: Yes, you understood correctly. Underscores are there just because they were there in the prototype. 
I just threw together a quick test to see how your suggestion works.
If you want me to make sure before you post a formal answer, that'll have to wait till tomorrow.
Thank you!

Comment: Yes, it works fine. Please add the answer so I could upvote it. 
You might want to remark that `concat` is not relevant to the matter.
Thank you!